# Same header.jsp for different web application

Tags: java, spring

I have a running web application with a functional header with js and css of it's own. Now I m trying to use the same header with all the features in my another application.

Instead of duplicating the code, I need to have some kind of a controller or servlet that can provide me this JSP in proper functional format.

Currently I have tried this approach mentioned below code in a servlet :

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

   CharArrayWriterResponse customResponse = new CharArrayWriterResponse(resp);

   req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/header_new.jsp").forward(req, customResponse);
   resp.getWriter().print(customResponse.getOutput());
  }
```

I m getting the response as html but stil not able to use it in another application using  tag.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: How about creating a new module, that contains the common jsp files? Then you could use that as dependency in the other projects

Comment: Thanks, but calling web application can be a java web application or a .net web application, so common jsp module won't work